# bash: parse number at the end of a long command

Tags: bash

I'm writing a shell script that will run a command and parse out the last few numbers (changes everytime).

Text to parse after running `npm run server` which outputs:

```
Please visit http;//mysite.com/id/2318
```

I want to parse out the value and assign it to `id`:

```
2318
```

My attempt:

```
id=$(echo npm run server | sed -n 's:.*id\/\(.*\)\n.*:\1:p')
```

Nothing is being returned.

Comment: BTW, does `npm run server` background itself?

Comment: `npm run server` doesn't have a number at the end.

Comment: To explain why my answer is long and hairy, btw: `foo=$(bar)` waits until `bar` has exited (well, closed its stdout, at least) before it assigns a value to `foo`. I'm **assuming** that you don't want to wait for `npm run server` to exit before your script proceeds (unless the service is closing stdout and self-backgrounding!), so that approach isn't open to you.

Comment: you noticed the http; instead of http:, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Addressing your original one-liner:

> My attempt:
>
> ```
> id=$(echo npm run server | sed -n 's:.*id\/\(.*\)\n.*:\1:p')
> ```
>
> Nothing
>   is being returned.

You could try this instead:

```
id=$(npm run server | sed -E -e 's:(^.*)(id/)(.*$):\3:g')
```

**NOTE:** This addresses **only** the component of your original attempt that ***obviously*** has some workability issues.  This doesn't take anything into account except the premise of your quoted output string that you supposedly get from running the command.  **i.e. I reproduced this using the following command:**

```
echo 'Please visit http;//mysite.com/id/2318' | sed -E -e 's:(^.*)(id/)(.*$):\3:g'
```

So assuming that when you run `npm run server`, you get the output `'Please visit http;//mysite.com/id/2318'` (which, by the way - I'd suggest might be http**:** // and not http**;**//), then this command should return just the `id` component.

---

#### Note that if it's stderr:

If the text your trying to filter is coming out of stderr and not stdout, you may in fact need to use this instead:

```
id=$(npm run server  &> >(sed -E -e 's:(^.*)(id/)(.*$):\3:g'))
```

For example, parsing the output of an unconfigured npm server:

```
06:38:23 ✗ :~ >npm run server
npm ERR! Darwin 15.5.0

06:38:23 ✗ :~ >npm run server | sed -E -e "s/(Darwin)/HELLO/g"
npm ERR! Darwin 15.5.0

06:38:56 ✗ :~ >npm run server &> >(sed -E -e "s/(Darwin)/HELLO/g")
npm ERR! HELLO 15.5.0
```

You can see about redirecting stderr in the `bash` manual:

> ```
> Redirecting Standard Output and Standard Error
>
>    Bash  allows both the standard output (file descriptor 1) and the stan-
>    dard error output (file descriptor 2) to  be  redirected  to  the  file
>    whose name is the expansion of word with this construct.
>  
>    There  are  two  formats  for  redirecting standard output and standard
>    error:
>  
>           &>word
>    and
>           >&word
>  
>    Of the two forms, the first is preferred.
> ```

Comment: Thanks, thought I'd checked and rechecked.

Comment: Better. The only caveat there is that this will only return and allow the rest of the script to be run if the service exits (or self-backgrounds) after printing that line. (Also, content in any *additional* lines will get captured into the variable; I'm taking "end of a long command" to mean that actual output is multi-line, and it's only this one line that's of interest).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I think your solution is more robust and it looks like you understand OP's *actual* intention with his workflow.  I'm more just coming at this from face value since those intentions aren't clear to me, and I could clearly see an error in the `sed` expression which was easily correctable and may have achieved the desired outcome

Comment: @CharlesDuffy given that from the point of view of the question in terms of search results, it was "parse number at the end of a long command"

Comment: Makes sense. If nothing else, this answer is likely to be helpful to others who find it from that direction.

Comment: @hmedia1 this is still failing for me. `npm run server` spawns a whole text of outputs but the `sed` does not seem to be capturing the right text

Comment: @user299709 can you copy and paste the contents of the console into a new note at https://ybin.me , then click the save (disk) button and paste the URL from the browser bar into the comments.  I'd like to take a look at what's going on.  Alternatively take a screenshot and add it as an edit to your question.

Comment: Also have you tried the solution offered by @CharlesDuffy ?

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming:

- That you want to invoke `npm run server` as a command.
- That this command at some point emits the given message *on its stdout* (as opposed to stderr, direct to the TTY, etc).
- That this command *does not* self-background, and that you want it to keep running even after that output is given.
- That it's not important that `npm run server` continue running after the shell script that started it has exited.

If all those assumptions are correct, consider a process substitution for this job:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
regex='Please visit .*/([[:digit:]]+)$'    # define a regex to search for the string
exec 3< <(npm run server)                  # attach output from "npm run server" to FD 3

## the action is here: searching through output from server until we find a match
while read -r server_output <&3; do        # loop reading a line at a time from the server
  if [[ $server_output =~ $regex ]]; then  # if a line matches the regex...
    id=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}                  # then put the first capture group in a variable
    break                                  # and stop looping further.
  fi
done

## after-the-fact: log success/failure, and set up any future output to be consumed
## ...so the server doesn't hang trying to write later output/logs to stdout w/ no readers.
if [[ $id ]]; then                         # if that variable contains a non-empty value
  echo "Detected server instance $id" >&2  # log it...
  cat </dev/fd/3 >/dev/fd/2 & cat_fd=$!    # start a background process to copy any further
                                           # stdout from service to stderr...
  exec 3<&-                                # then close our own copy of the handle.
else
  echo "Unable to find an id in stdout of 'npm run server'" >&2
  exit 1
fi

## and we're done: if you like, run your other code here.

## also: if you want to wait until the server has exited
##       (or at least closed its stdout), consider:
[[ $cat_fd ]] && wait "$cat_fd"
```